# How to get Total Capacity and Utilisation metrics from a Kafka Cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted to collect snapshot of capacity and utilisation from the Kafka Cluster for a period of time in order to create some sample report.Is there any REST API's or JMX Metrics such that i get these numbers for a whole cluster?